# Unable to install python version

Tags: python, ubuntu, vagrant

My Ubuntu version in my vagrant is 14.04, and my python version is 2.7 which restricts me, is there a way I can update the python version to 3.10 (when I do it says: couldn't find any package by regex python 3.10) or get Ubuntu 20.04 on vagrant if it's impossible to get python 3.10 on Ubuntu 14.04

Tried:

Sudo apt-get install python3.10

Got: unable to locate package python3.10

Comment: 14.04 is nearly 9 years old; why can't you update the OS?

Comment: Version *22* was released earlier this year.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: update your box in vagrant to use ubuntu 20.04 (`ubuntu/focal64`) and recreate the VM